# Consigo preencher um DataGrid com um List<T>?

Tags: c#, wpf

Como faço para preencher um `DataGrid` a partir de um `List` tipado?

Seria possível, gerar as colunas automaticamente?

Comment: Para complementar sua pergunta, edite a sua pergunta, não a resposta dada. Para adicionar uma resposta, dê a sua própria resposta.

Comment: Caique, para complementar a resposta, deixe um comentário. O autor decide se quer ou não incluir o conteúdo que você sugere.

Comment: Ah, ok. Desculpe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim `ItemSource` do `DataGrid` (vi que o seu caso é WPF) você consegue passar qualquer enumeração (IList, ICollection, etc)

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = (new List<T>());
```

Aonde *`new List<T>()`* é a sua lista.

Para habilitar a criação automática de colunas, coloque ***True*** em `AutoGenerateColumns` no seu `DataGrid` do `WPF`.

Comment: Obrigado cara, ajudou bastante. Eu fiz como disse e quando executei, nada... percebi que havia três linhas no DataGrid, mas não tinha coluna alguma. Procurei alguma propriedade ou método que gerasse, achei o AutoGenerateColumns e deixei como true e funcionou! Obrigado :)

Comment: Ok, que bom que deu certo